# Symfony2 db design

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I asked a question but now realise it may be related to my design.  So, I have an Alert, and each Alert can have one or more AlertFlightNumbers.  So my Alert entity is like so

```
**
 * Alert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="alert")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Nick\AlertBundle\Repository\AlertRepository")
 *
 */
class Alert
{
    //all the usual stuff

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AlertFlightNumbers", mappedBy="availabilityAlert")
     */
    private $flightNumbers;

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getFlightNumbers()
    {
        return $this->flightNumbers;
    }

    /**
     * @param AlertFlightNumbers $flightNumber
     * @return AvailabilityAlert
     */
    public function addFlightNumber(AlertFlightNumbers $flightNumber)
    {
        if (!$this->flightNumbers->contains($flightNumber)) {
            $this->flightNumbers->add($flightNumber);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

So I have the flight numbers collection in my Alert Entity.  Then in my AlertFlightNumbers entity, I have

```
/**
 * AlertFlightNumbers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="alert_flight_numbers", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="alert_id", columns={"alert_id", "flight_number"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_4D3E3675D28831F9", columns={"availability_alert_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class AvailabilityAlertFlightNumbers
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert", inversedBy="flightNumbers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="availability_alert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $availabilityAlert; 

    /**
     * Get flightNumber
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFlightNumber()
    {
        return $this->flightNumber;
    }
}
```

So from what I have seen, this is the standard way to link these type of things so that an Alert can have one or more FlightNumbers.

My problem is this.  I have a Listener tied up to the Alert entity in which I do

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    if ($entity instanceof Alert) {
        $this->alert = $entity;
    }
}
```

Essentially, that gets me the persisted Alert Entity Object.  Using that Object, if I do

> \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($alert->getFlightNumbers());

I end up with

```
object(stdClass)[398]
  public '__CLASS__' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AlertFlightNumbers' (length=55)
  public 'id' => int 69
  public 'flightNumber' => string 'VS7' (length=3)
  public 'availabilityAlert' => 
    object(stdClass)[414]
      public '__CLASS__' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert' (length=42)
      public 'id' => int 65
      public 'searchCommand' => string 'A20APRLONLAX' (length=12)
      public 'isConnecting' => string 'no' (length=2)
      public 'lastUpdated' => string 'DateTime' (length=8)
      public 'isDeleted' => int 0
      public 'alertStatus' => string 'Active' (length=6)
      public 'bookingClass' => string 'Array(1)' (length=8)
      public 'pseudo' => string 'Array(1)' (length=8)
      public 'flightNumbers' => string 'Array(1)' (length=8)
```

When I call the method getFlightNumbers, this is not what I would really expect.  Really, I want the getFlightNumber function from AlertFlightNumbers to be used so that I am returned with only VS7 instead of all the other data.

So the main question is how do I get access to the Alerts Flight Numbers only?  p.s. I dont know why it list the fields as public because they shouldnt be, and if I try to access them I get the private warning.

Thanks

Comment: You will save yourself so much trouble if you just take the time to read the documentation and implement a few examples.  Doctrine is an Object Relational Manager.  You really need to understand what that means.

Comment: I was using the docs to come up with what I did.  But then according to the docs the following should really work, but it doesnt  $alert->getFlightNumbers()->getFlightNumber()

Comment: Why would think that?  getFlightNumbers returns a collection of AlertFlightNumber entities.